# How do you draw a line from one corner of the stage to the other?

Tags: actionscript, graphics, line, draw

I am completely perplexed. I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627187/how-come-drawing-this-line-at-0-0-doesnt-really-draw-it-at-0-0) question and it (any mentioned solution) doesn't seem to be working at all.

**All** I want is to draw a line from one corner to the other.

Here again is the link to the SWF file I have (it's embedded in an HTML document): [test.html](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/test.html)

Here is the source:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000000);

            graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
            graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        }

    }

}
```

It just *doesn't* work! The line goes from somewhere offscreen to about the middle of the stage. What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try restarting Flash (or w/e you're creating the swf with)?  I have had issues similar to this in the past, and restarting Flash was all it took to fix them. I don't know why, but every once in a while Flash just goofs up on me.

Comment: @wallacoloo: Ya... I tried it with the ActiveX player, and the plugin player. Same result. I'm using FlashDevelop, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compiled your SWF to be 800x600, while your embed is at 350x350. If you want your code to work anyway, you should set the stage's [`scaleMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) to [`StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html#NO_SCALE) and the [`align`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#align) to [`StageAlign.TOP_LEFT`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageAlign.html#TOP_LEFT). By default, they are `StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER` and `StageAlign.TOP`, which makes your SWF display at about 466x350 (maintaining 4:3 ratio), thus having its upper left corner at about (-58,0) and it's lower right at about (408, 350) (being horizontally centered (relatively to area of the embed)).

Comment: jeez... so it WAS a problem with his embed. But how do you know his SWF was set to be 800x600, not actually 350x350?

Comment: Thank you everyone - I was beginning to think I had lost it.

Comment: @jonathanasdf: well, 1. it's the FD default setting, 2. if you download the SWF and open it in the standalone player, it will open at its prefered size. of course there are plenty of other ways to find out. :)

Comment: ahh.. never thought of downloading the swf! :)

Answer (score 1):

well i'm perplexed too. Copying the EXACT SAME CODE and running the swf WORKS. http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1271209077

so i swear it's something wrong with your embed tag or something.

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop. Is this a known issue or what?

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop too. I don't know why it's not working for you.... can someone else confirm whether it works for them or not?

Comment: @jonathanasdf: What would be the command for manually compiling with `mxmlc`?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html

just plain mxmlc filename.as

Comment: @jonathanasdf: Tried that - I just end up with the same thing... with a blue background now.

Comment: this is really, really, really weird.